# Pull SOAP XML data using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, web-services, soap

im new here.I just have a question about pulling XML data using a nodeJS application. I saw that there were some examples using .Net and java. But I am not using these technologies and I am required to use nodeJS to pull SOAP data. I have created an express server to run the server but I do not know what else to do.

WSDL: https://webservices1.autotask.net/atservices/1.5/atws.wsdl

Please see below for my implementation and creation of server

```
//Server.js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/",(req,res)=> {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain")
    res.setHeader("X-Powered-By","EXPRESS")
    res.sendStatus(200).json("Helo");
})


const port= process.env.PORT || 7000;

app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usally use [Boomerang - SOAP & REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah?hl=en) to import SOAP services. then you can see body, headers, endpoint here and easy to use at any nodejs package like `request`, `http`, `axios`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the packages from npm.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

You could read more on the documentation. Also, this link may help you.

https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-perform-soap-requests-with-node-js-4a9627070eb6